# Column doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Was wondering if someone could help me out a little with this query:

```
SELECT u1.id,count(DISTINCT u2.userstatus) as TEMPCOLUMN FROM users AS u1
JOIN friendssym ON u1.id = friendssym.user_id
JOIN (SELECT * FROM users) as u2 ON friendssym.friend_id=u2.id
WHERE TEMPCOLUMN=1 
group by u1.id;
```

I want to only have results where the count (which is renamed) is equal to 1. I get an error with this query:

```
 ERROR:  column "tempcolumn" does not exist
```

But the column *should* exist, right? Can anyone assist? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference a column alias in the WHERE clause.

```
  SELECT u1.id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT u2.userstatus) as TEMPCOLUMN 
    FROM USERS AS u1
    JOIN friendssym ON u1.id = friendssym.user_id
    JOIN USERS as u2 ON friendssym.friend_id = u2.id      
GROUP BY u1.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u2.userstatus) = 1
```

In traditional SQL, the earliest you can reference a column alias is the `ORDER BY` clause.  But MySQL and SQL Server allow access in the `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: I was using a column alias because WHERE wouldn't let me use the COUNT directly (it says it can't use aggregates) but the HAVING works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Airjoe: Yep, can't use aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, MIN or MAX) in the WHERE clause outside of a subquery - need to use the HAVING clause for that.